# Would this code cause memory leak?

Tags: typescript

I have the following two classes

```
export class T{
  constructor(
    public c:string,
    public s:string,
    public t:string
  ){}
}

export class ST{
  's-t':Array<T>;
  constructor(
    st:Array<T>
  ){
    this['s-t'] = st;
  }
}
```

In the `.ts` file of my `Angular` component, I create a variable

```
 st:ST;
```

then initialise it in the constructor

```
this.st=new ST([]);
```

And when I get a response from the server, I reassign `st` to the body of the response.

```
this.st = JSON.parse(response['additional-info']);
```

As I am not freeing the previously allocated memory (`this.st = new ST([]]`), would there be a memory leak?

Comment: Javascript's garbage collector automatically frees unreferenced objects.

Comment: thanks. Happy to accept answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's garbage collector automatically frees unreferenced objects.